# What exactly are .jd files used for?

Tags: java, html, javadoc

I've been working with .jd files at my work, building it in my local computer to convert it to html...

However, I'm still confused about what .jd files are for? I did some research and the definition is that: "Javadoc is a tool that generates html documentation (similar to the reference pages at java.sun.com) from Javadoc comments in the code. "

When I'm looking at the .jd file code, they look very much like html. They have the `<p>` tags and the `<li>` tags. Do the programmers write javadoc code? Or Javadoc is a tool(which is very vague to me, a software tool named Javadoc to generate .jd files?) to extract comments from Java code?

Can someone help me understanding it? Since I'm not working directly with generating .jd files, it is quite hard to understand its use and what exactly it is...

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's very uncommon to actually see a `.jd` file. Javadoc is normally contained inline in the code, and then processed into ordinary `.html`.

Comment: This is what I'm confused about Javadoc...You said that Javadoc is contained inline in the code..Let's say the code is Java code, so you mean the javadoc is only the comment inside the Java code? If that is the case, so there should be a tool to extract all the comments(as what you said, the javadoc) to extract them and make them a .jd file, correct?

Comment: No, it makes them an HTML file. Did you actually see a `.jd` file anywhere?

Comment: Yes. We received .jd files, but they don't have comments inside...only html tags and contents following @jd.body. So I got confused..If .jd file doesn't have comments, it's a javadoc file still?

Comment: I've never heard of a `.jd` file. That sounds like some intermediate format. Modern Javadoc reads Java files and outputs HTML directly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's very helpful! Yea, somehow they send us .jd files...maybe they have a different working pipline...

Answer (score 2):

JavaDoc is written by developers with comments embedded within their source code.

So, for example:

```
/**
 * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen. 
 * The url argument must specify an absolute {@link URL}. The name
 * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument. 
 * <p>
 * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the 
 * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
 * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives 
 * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen. 
 *
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
        try {
            return getImage(new URL(url, name));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }
 }
```

This example is documenting a method called getImage.

JavaDoc is great because it's documentation that developers can write as-they-code, right alongside their code, and after running through the generator they have nice technical documentation that others can easily read.

The reason that you are seeing html in the .jd files is that for formatting reasons, some html can be embedded in the JavaDoc (see example)

Comment: Thank you! But the .jd file I'm seeing doesn't have any comments, just `page.title=blahblahblah` on the first line and `@jd:body` on the second line, then the following are almost all html code with several instances of tags like `{@docRoot}`. why is that?  Also, according to your explanation, I'm guessing the comments in the javaDoc example you provided above would be uncommented in the html converted from jd files (or maybe not, because it depends on whom the html files are for)?

Comment: @Penny what I was describing is typical JavaDoc usage. Perhaps .jd files are an internal format used at your company?

Comment: I see no reference to .jd files here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html

Answer (score 1):

A Javadoc is a method of converting class, method, and other documentation comments within Java code into a readable HTML API documentation format for people to look at.

Just about all of the documentation on specific classes and methods within Java are formed from Javadoc files.

TL;DR: They convert comments to documentation pages.